# div boxes won't line up using attribute display:inline-block;

Tags: html, css, alignment

A couple things I'm really confused with about my code:

1. Without the "vertical-align" line that's commented out, the div boxes don't line up.
2. A `<p>` tag inside a `<div>` adds an extra space to the top.
3. The picture does not show up at all.

   ```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
   <html>
   <head>
   <style>
   div {
       display: inline-block;
       margin-left: 5px;
       height: 100px;
       width: 100px;
       border-radius: 50%;
       text-align: center;
       line-height: 100px;
   <!--vertical-align: middle; -->
       border: 2px dashed #008000;
   }
   </style>
   <title>Frends n shiz</title>
   </head>
   <body>
       <div><p>billy</p><img href="http://i.imgur.com/mango.jpg" /></div>
       <div><p>bob</p></div>
       <div>joe</div>
       <div>schmoe</div>
       <div><p>jane</p></div>
       <div>bane</div>
   </body>
   </html>
   ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The picture does not show up at all.

It should be `src` on image not `href`:

```
<img src="http://i.imgur.com/mango.jpg" />
```

Instead of

```
<img href="http://i.imgur.com/mango.jpg" />
```

> A P tag inside a div adds an extra space to the top.

And yes default `p` is for paragraph so it will wrap down has a default margin added by the browser. You can reset `p` margin though to `p{margin:0}`

> Without the "vertical-align" line that's commented out, the div boxes don't line up.

After the above fixes You can use `float:left` instead of `display:inline-block` and see the difference on how it is rendered, not sure how you want it to be..

Something like **[this](http://jsfiddle.net/4TK9F/)** ??

Answer (score 0):

Your code is really weird, many issues like:

```
img should use src instead of href
You need to set the 'p' margin to 0
For vertical-align: middle you should use display: table-cell
Instead of 'line-height', you should use 'height' (if necessary) etc.
```

Check this jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/grsVp/1/

Comment: line-height has is used: gives a height to container and set 1 line of text at vertical middle

Answer (score 0):

> A couple things I'm really confused with about my code:

1. Without the "vertical-align" line that's commented out, the div
   boxes don't line up. ***This is what it's meant for***, use it ! **don't use float instead !**
2. A `<p>` tag inside a `<div>` adds an extra space to the top. *This is a normal behavior,reset the defaut margin (0 1em) to 0. **as already said***
3. The picture does not show up at all.*Wrong attribute to link the pic **as already said***